# Disassemble, edit and re-assembly iOS ipa apps

Tags: disassembly, assembly, ios

I'm trying to get jailbreak statistics for a University project related to security in mobile devices. My purpose is to disassemble, add a sample code and re-assemble to obtain a runnable iOS app again.

I have read a lot about IDA, IDA pro, HEX-Rays, and o'tool to disassemble an ipa file.

Since i'm working with a macbook pro, i think that using otool to disassemble an '.ipa' file is the best and faster way. I have tried it with a non-signed `.ipa` and I have obtained the assembly code.

Then, I have difficulties. I have tried to create a new Xcode project, import this assembly code and try to compile it to generate a new app, without inserting new code just to simplify the process.

But when i tried to compile, Xcode fails in every single code line.

I think that my problem is, that the process described:

1. Disassemble with otool
2. Import the code in XCode
3. Compile and build
4. Obtain the new app

Is not correct.

Comment: I was trying to add some functionality, but the solution of edit in HEX, is not good for add code. I was thinking to create my own code in XCode, compile and add it to the main program, but i think this will not work because my program will use memory positions that are already used in the main program. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to rebuild with XCode. You'd need to patch the decrypted app with a hex editor in order to make your desired changes.

See http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1363777-how-to-make-mods-for-ios/ for a sample walkthrough.

Comment: Hello Jason, I have seen in that forum the way to edit some things changing values in HEX after decrypting the code. I was trying to add some functionality, but this way to edit HEX is really hard to add code. I was thinking to create my own code in XCode, compile and add it to the main program, but i think this will not work because my program will use memory positions that are already used in the main program.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### Depending on your need

If you need to **change the behavior of Objective-C** (possibly also Swift) **methods or classes**, it is way easier to **create a tweak** for the app. There are also many advantages in doing so, one of them being that a tweak can be un/-installed easily at a large scale (just create a source for Cydia with your tweak).

Note that if you need a one-time and *non permanent* change, consider using **Cycript** instead. It is really straightforward (cycript.org). Just inspect the target app's headers with *Clutch* and *class-dump-z* in order to have an idea of what you want to modify and you're good to go.

#### Creating a tweak

In order to create a tweak, you can use [**iOSOpenDev**](http://www.iosopendev.com) (and its [*Logos*](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Logos) template) or **Theos**. iOSOpendev allows you to create your tweak in Xcode and install it to your device, making it really convenient to use.